# Azure Get Ip address of hosting server for Google Cloud Services

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, google-cloud-messaging, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web Api 2 project that sends Push Notification to an android app via Google Cloud Services. Running locally, I can get my machine's ip address and set this in my included IP's for my service api in Google API console, which works fine. However, I now deployed to azure and this is no longer working. I did an ip looking on my site name, so for example mySite.azurewebsites.net, where the site is hosted, but this does not seem to work.

Is there a way I can get the ip address of the service that is hosting my asp web api project in azure?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2014/05/05/how-to-get-a-static-ip-address-for-your-microsoft-azure-web-site.aspx). This might help you out in finding out the the IP address of the web api project you have hosted on Azure.